# elevator goes up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

An elevator goes up 180 m by first accelerating at a constant rate of 1.0 m/s2, then staying at a constant
speed of 9 m/s and then decelerating at a constant rate of -­‐‑1.0 m/s2. How much time does it take the
elevator to go from bottom to top?

so i know that d = 180m
a = 1.0 m/$s^2$ for the first part
v = 9 m/s
and for the last part a = -1 m/$s^2$

Im not sure which kinematics to use, there are two that I tried using

d=$v_i$t + 1/2a$t^2$

and

v$_f$ = $v_i$ + at

I tried to find the time for the part where the elevator is accelerating by doing

9 = 0 + 1t

so t = 9s

then I tried to find the distance for which the elevator was going up by doing

d = 0(9) + 1/2(1)(92) and got d = 40.5

so then the d for when its decelerating is 139.5 which i plugged into

d=$v_i$t + 1/2a$t^2$

and tried to solve for t but i ended up getting a weird answer with a square root.

where did i go wrong here?

Comment: Hey welcome. You did a good job writing your first question. You missed that the elevator will go at a constant speed for some time, so it doesn't decelerate for the full 139.5 m. It goes at a constant speed for a while until it has just enough time to come to a stop by decelerating at 1 $m/s^2$ while making the total distance 180 m.

Comment: so i break it up in three parts?

Comment: yes there are three parts: one where it accelerates, one where it goes at a constant speed, and one where it decelerates.

Comment: can i use this equation for all parts vf = vi + at?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs actually, I wouldn't say this is such a well-written question. These kinds of questions where someone presents a problem with an incorrect solution and just asks where they went wrong are not really appropriate here. (That being said, alexthefourth, you did do much better than other people who don't even try to solve the question at all.)

Comment: where is the place to ask such questions? I am asking for help, not just answers

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if one makes a v-t graph using the information. The v-t graph would be trapezium OABC, O being the origin. As the elevator starts from rest and finally comes to stop, and the rate of acceleration and deceleration are equal, the distances as well as the time taken are same in these phases of motion. Thus trapezium OABC is an isosceles trapezium i.e., area of the two triangles are equal.
Let $t_1$=time accelerating, $t_3$=time decelerating and $t_2$=time when elevator moves uniformly.
Area of OABC = Distance travelled = 180 m
$$\frac12v_{max}(t_2+t_1+t_2+t_3)=180$$
As $v_{max}=9m/s$ and $t_1=t_3$ hence:
$$t_1+t_2=20$$

By considering, slope=acceleration:
$$\frac9t_1=1$$

Solving the two: $$T=t_1+t_2+t_3=29s$$